# How to cast a java.lang.Class<Mapper> to java.lang.class<TableMapper>

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

See the bottom for the solution.

I'm trying to write some generic handling code, but in 1 of the sub-classes, it requires a Class that is more specific.

So the base class as a field of type Class, and in the subclass I'm trying to cast that Class object to type Class which is a subclass of org.​apache.​hadoop.​hbase.​mapreduce.Mapper.

I get the following error from Netbeans:

```
"Incompatible types
required: java.lang.Class<org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapper>
found: java.lang.class<capture#3 of ? extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper>"
```

when I try the following code

```
Class<TableMapper> tableMapperClass = null;
if( mapperClass.equals(TableMapper.class) ) {
    tableMapperClass = TableMapper.class.asSubclass(mapperClass);

    //do stuff
}
```

and I get:

```
incompatible types
required: java.lang.Class<org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapper>
found: java.lang.Class<capture#8 of ? extends org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapper>
```

for

```
Class<TableMapper> tableMapperClass = null;
if( mapperClass.equals(TableMapper.class) ) {
    tableMapperClass = mapperClass.asSubclass(TableMapper.class);

    //do stuff
}
```

Ok, got the answer from my co-worker, looks like this should work:

```
Class<? extends TableMapper> tableMapperClass = null;
if( mapperClass.equals(TableMapper.class) ) {
    tableMapperClass = mapperClass.asSubclass(TableMapper.class);

    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to assign a class to *tableMapperClass* that is actually a subclass of TableMapper, then you need to change the type of the variable.  Instead, use:

```
Class<? extends TableMapper> tableMapperClass = null;
```

and now you can assign TableMapper.class or any subclass to this variable.  When you write `Class<TableMapper>` you are promising that the variable will be exactly TableMapper.class or null.

Another example:

```
Class<Number> number = Integer.class; // does not compile
Number number = new Integer(1); // compiles fine
Class<? extends Number> number = Integer.class; // also ok
```

Note that you can do different things with `Class<Number>` then you can with `Class<? extends Number>`.  For example, you can call a constructor of `Class<Number>`, because you know the class.  You can't do that with `Class<? extends Number>` because the constructors are not defined at compile time.

Similarly with, say, `List<Number>` vs `List<? extends Number>`.  You can call list.add(7) on a variable of type `List<Number>`, but you can't do that on a `List<? extends Number>` because you don't know the type of the second list.  It might be a `List<Double>` for example, in which case adding an Integer is not allowed.

Generics are weird.  :)  Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup, exactly the solution my co-worker got me and I put in my edited question. I agree, Generics can be quite weird.